# TypeError: c.diff is not a function and Property 'diff' does not exist on type 'Date'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs, luxon

I am having some issue in my google chrome console where I am receiving `Uncaught TypeError: c.diff is not a function` and in my vscode when I hover in my code, here I am receiving 'diff' is not exist in a 'Date'. But when I test my code in code sample in other code editor I m receiving expected output. This is converting process from moment into luxon. Here is the code sample:. But here I am this import the luxon:

```
   // import * as luxon from 'luxon';
  import { DateTime, Duration } from 'luxon';
```

Here is my my code sample which I hover in vscode and giving me error:

```
const timezone = 'Europe/Lisbon';
const checkInString = '';

const checkIn = DateTime.fromISO(checkInString, { zone: timezone }).toJSDate();
const currentDuration = Duration.fromMillis(checkIn.diff(DateTime.utc())).as(
  'minutes'
);

console.log(`This current time luxon: `, currentDuration);
```

```
Output: Error: checkIn.diff is not a function
```

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `toJSDate` which produces a native `Date` object, not a Luxon DateTime object. Then you are trying to call Luxon's `diff()` on it

Answer (score 1):

your time zone **Europe/Spain** is invalid

use this

```
const checkInGoL = DateTime.fromISO(checkInLuxon5K, {
  zone: 'Europe/Lisbon', //or any timezone listed below
})
```

you can get complete list of timezones here : [complete list of timezones](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json)

Comment: Thank you @Ragnar I am still getting error in here const checkInGoL =                       
  ```   DateTime.fromISO(checkInLuxon5K, {
  zone: 'Europe/Lisbon',
}).toJSDate();



console.log(
  `This luxon Method 10 :  `,
  Duration.fromMillis(checkInGoL.diff(DateTime.now())).as('minutes')
);```

Comment: Error: checkInGoL.diff is not a function @Ragnar

Comment: remove .toJsDate() in that method

Comment: In my VSCode now I am receiving this error after removing .toJSDate().         Argument of type 'Duration' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

Comment: still same issue. @Ragnar

Comment: checkInGoL.diff(DateTime.now()) return type Duration but  Duration.fromMillis takes number as input. you are seeing this error because you are using typescript.
check the documentation and please describe what you want to do with Duratio.fromMillis /

Comment: Hello @Ragnar I had update my logic example, check the link